# How to make the background color of the chart as gradient using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, linechart

I am trying to make a line chart using Chart.js in React.
I did not use DOM to create and reach canvas.
I can arrange the background color but I just want to make it as gradient. How can I do that?

**My codes below:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Line } from "@reactchartjs/react-chart.js";

const data = {
  labels: ["day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day5", "day6"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Your BMI",
      data: [28.3, 28, 27, 27.6, 25, 25.6],
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(10,10,10,.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(152,222,217,0.2)"
    }
  ]
};




const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

const LineChart = () => (
  <>
    <Line data={data} options={options} />
  </>
);

export default LineChart;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lwg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the canvas "createLinearGradient" method.

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasGradient/addColorStop

Example: https://codepen.io/alexgill/pen/MWbjXOP

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(10,10,10,.2)');   
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');


const data = {
  labels: ["day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day5", "day6"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Your BMI",
      data: [28.3, 28, 27, 27.6, 25, 25.6],
      backgroundColor : gradient,
      borderColor: "rgba(152,222,217,0.2)"
    }
  ]
};
```